# Best way to resize square button programmatically for new iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, autoresizingmask

I would like to know what is the best way to resize an unknown number of square buttons. My view should look like this on every iPhone:

[image]

At the moment I´m doing it like this, but it doesn't feel correct:

Here I calculate the width of the screen:

```
CGFloat getDisplayWidth() {

CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
return result.width;
}
```

Here I resize the button:

```
CGFloat tilePaddingIphone = 8.0f;
self.displayWidth = getDisplayWidth(); 
CGSize buttonSize = CGSizeMake((self.displayWidth-buttonPaddingIphone)/2, (self.displayWidth-buttonPaddingIphone)/2);

self.button = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x_coordinate, y_coordinate, buttonSize.width, buttonSize.height)];
```

The problem is when I do it like this, I can´t test it with the "resizable iPhone" Simulator, because `getDisplayWidth` always gives me 768.0f back when I run the simulator
and it doesn´t matter when I change the size of the Simulator.

So it's really hard to test if my button would work on the new iPhone 6! What is the "correct" way of resizing such a case?

Comment: Shouldn't you be getting the view controller view's size instead of UIScreen size? preferrably after the view has loaded (viewDidLoad sometimes reports the wrong width and height if your in landscape mode until view completely loaded) UIScreen size shouldn't change, that's the device's screen size, no?

Comment: Thats right it would be better to get the size from the ViewController, but in my Case it doesn´t matter because UIScreen and the size of my ViewController are always the same :)

Comment: Maybe its better to use the autoresizing mask, or is this no opinion?

Comment: A view controller's view size changes when you rotate the device. In landscape mode, the view's width and height changes. I don't think it's the same size as screen size.

Comment: You´re right, i try to use something like: self.view.bounds.size.width, but it also make no difference!

Comment: Did you call self.view.bounds.size.width in viewDidLoad() or viewDidAppear() ? You need to put it inside viewDidAppear() to see a difference since viewDidLoad() may not actually finished setting up the view yet, hence landscape dimension might always appear the same as portrait dimensions.